# Finding Leaflet Layer Dasharray

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a document from a leaflet map. The legend from the map features will not be part of the map but a separate area on the document. I am trying to get the Layer information such  as color and dasharray(solid, dashed....) information from each layer.

I have used feature.option.style, but I get function style(feature) {return....}. I want to get the actual values.

```
  var lyrs = map._layers;
        for (var f in map._layers) {
            var feature = map._layers[f];
            alert(feature.options.style);
            return false;
        }
```

I get this:

```
function style(feature) {
  return {
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'black',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Rights, "geojson", "parcel") 
  }; 
}
```

I want to be able to get:

```
fillColor:black;
dashArray: '3'
```

Comment: Are you iterating through individual geometries (`L.Path` instances), or `L.LayerGroup`s?

Comment: I am getting the map layers within the map using the map._layers call. All layers were placed into the map one at a time (geometry from PostGres) using GeoJSON. They weren't grouped. I thought there would be a getStyle() type of function to counter the setStyle() function. I could not find any information on it.

Comment: If you're using `L.GeoJSON` then you're grouping them (because `L.GeoJSON` inherits from `L.LayerGroup`).  So, once again: when you iterate, are you getting instances of `L.LayerGroup` (or `L.GeoJSON`), or are you getting instances of `L.Path` (`L.Polyline`s and `L.Polygon` s)?

Comment: The Layers that are being loaded in this instance are single feature layers. Since my Leaflet knowledge is still growing, I interpret that as not a group although Leaflet may see that as a group of one. I am iterating through all the layers in the map one by one to look at each layer's properties. There are a few layers in the map. Two polygon layers and one Polyline layer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the style call the code should read as follows

```
  var lyrs = map._layers;
        for (var f in lyrs) {
            var feature = map._layers[f];
            var properties = feature.options.dashArray;
            alert(properties);
            return false;
        }
```

This returns the value of 3. Exactly what was desired. The same call could be used to find the weight, opacity, color, fillOpacity or fillColor